# java shell execute for php command

Tags: java, javafx

I wrote a shell execute program in java for `php localhost:8080` with root directory `/src/MyForm/` and file name is `index.php`. Directory Im passing from a string.
my code is like this.

```
    String root = "/src/MyForm";
    String[] command = {"php", "-S", "localhost:80 -t "+ root};
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

im getting output like this

> Not Found
>   The requested resource / was not found on this server.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thXJr.png)

What i'm missing ?

Comment: Your port are differents, the root path don't point to your `index.php` file. You should set the full path for your `index.php`. Try something like this : `String[] command = {"php", "-S", "localhost:8080 -t " + fullpath + "index.php"};` http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php for more details.

Comment: thank you so much . I fixed it.

Comment: Post your response. It could help someone else.

Comment: `Process process = null;
            String[] command1 = {"php", "-S", "localhost:80", "-t" + root1};
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command1);`